# How can I list out bracketed text in Linux CLI in a readable format? Apache Geode node names & info

Tags: command-line, vim

I'm working with [Apache Geode nodes](https://geode.apache.org/), all of the work is being done via the Linux CLI. Normally when I edit the config files (with VIM) the text looks like this:

```
"nodes": {"long_UUID_here": {"node_uuid": "another_long_string_here", pair_uuid:" null, 
"is_admin_node": false, "ip_address": "ip-or-fqnd.domain.com", "preferred_addresses": {}, 
"node_name": shortname.domain.com", "membership_state": null, "region": null}
```

...and that's just **one** node. There are often several of them, and the text is just all globbed together in a big hard-to-read mess. What would make this a ton easier is if I could view and edit the file like so:

```
"nodes": {  
    "long_UUID_here": {  
        "node_uuid": "another_long_string_here",  
        "pair_uuid:" null,  
        "is_admin_node": false,
        "ip_address": "ip-or-fqnd.domain.com", 
        "preferred_addresses": {}, 
        "node_name": shortname.domain.com",
        "membership_state": null,
        "region": null
}
```

I know this is possible and I've seen it before, but I don't know how it's done.

Update: I have to point out, this is a SLES Appliance (often with no internet access) so **I cannot install any app**, such as `jq`

Comment: Is that supposed to be valid JSON? If so, you could use jq or similar to format it: https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/19950/205

Comment: Thank you, @muru. These are not actually JSON files, but you're right to say the layout is of course similar...so I'm actually not sure. These are like `.dat` files. The issue is that I'm working from a Linux appliance (closed source), so I cannot install a package and it does not have the `jq` utility.

Comment: What do you have available? Python? Whilst you may not be able to install a package can you install a binary in say ~/bin ?

Comment: Thanks, yes, the appliances either have Python 2 (older ones) or Python 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague of mine from DevOps showed me how to do this with `sed` + regEx + `json.tool`:

```
`echo sed -nre "/clusterMembership/ s/^[^']+'([^']+)','([^']+)'.*/\2/p" /path/to/file/here/node.file.config | python -m json.tool
```